# How to search by keyword MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, search, keyword

I made two tables

1. for stored keywords
2. have article titles and keywords

In the article table, I'm storing keywords id in set form like (1,2,3,6,7)

now I want to search by keywords and title by the maximum occurrence of user value;

example:
keywords Table
|keyword|id |
| ----- | - |
| pen   | 1 |
| paper | 2 |
| pencil| 3 |
| A4    | 4 |
| marker| 5 |

Article table
title                         keyword
Magical pencil with paper         1,2,4

user search magical pen

How can search efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Well the best solution is to make that field shouldn't contain comma separated all keywords values like `1,2,3,4`

You should manage its many to many table

For example:

- keywords
- articles
- keywords_to_articles (id, keyword_id, article_id)

After doing that, your database will be at 3rd Normal form and easy to execute your query by doing

```
select a.*
from articles a
join keywords_to_articles ka on ka.article_id = a.id
join keywords k on k.id = ka.keyword_id and k.name = '$keyword'
```

Here I am assuming that in keywords table you are storing in `name` field.

Doing like above mentioned will be an efficient way.

Comment: That you need to use `count` and `group by clause`